# difference in speed due to distance from router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am using my university wifi network and router is around 5-6m distance from my room. When I try to connect to the network with my phone despite of getting good signal bars I am getting poor speed and when I get near to router speed is  very good  in the same phone. But at some distance is zero.  I know with distance to router speed decreases but the difference I am observing is very high.....???

Answer (score 1):

You are probably experiencing interference from other routers in the surrounding area. You only get a good speed if your router overpowers all signals in the area, which happens when you are physically close to it (usable signal strength in busy areas decreases by exponentially with an exponent of 4 to 6 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_loss#Loss_exponent))). So you might have a good signal, but there is too much interference for any usable data to get through uninterrupted.

You would be best off by using an unused WiFi channel, especially in the 5 GHz band (since it is usually less crowded and there is more bandwidth allocated to that band). A WiFi analyzer tool would be able to help you find an unused channel.

If that fails, some access points have technology to deal with interference (Cisco CleanAir), but these might be too expensive.

Comment: Could one router broadcasting multiple networks on the same channel also cause interference? It seems like this is the case at Gagan's university...

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the "WiFi Analyzer" app on your phone. It is available on Android and Windows Phone. Using this, you can get a more detailed look at the signal strength than the built in signal bars. The signal strength bars on your phone could be slow in updating their status, and give a wrong impression.

A lot of things can reduce WiFi signal strength, most specifically, walls.

Also, when testing the speed of your connection, make sure to do it in a uniform way, to make sure nothing else can be influencing the speed. So, use a speed-testing website, and not the download speed of your current torrent or something similar...

Comment: I have used wifi analyser apps they show signal strength of the network (-60dBM). Is there any way that I can get good speed.

Comment: A signal strength of -60dBM is nearly perfect. This probably means that the WiFi signal is not the cause of the slow connection speed. Could you post the up and download speed results of this website: http://www.speedtest.net/ while your signal strength is -60dBM? thx

Comment: 8 mbps download speed and 2mbps upload speed when I was near the router and when I was in my room it was 0.3 Mbps download speed and 0.2 upload speed.

Comment: And the signal strength is also -60dBM when you are in your room? (just making sure...I'm getting out of ideas otherwise)

Comment: There is one more problem that when I try to connect to the network from my room, it takes times to connect .But when go near the router it just click and connected ..

Comment: That doesn't sound abnormal given the slow connection. This indicates a low signal strenth. Is the signal strength also -60dBM in your room?

Comment: It is exactly between -70 and -60 right now.

Comment: Interesting. How about @mtak's remark? Are there other WiFi networks with equal or greather signal strength?

Comment: yes around 5-6  other networks.

Comment: How many on the same channel, or nearby channels? Looks like that might be the cause... You could ask your University IT department to switch the WiFi router to a less busy channel.

Comment: I can't show you pictures, due to reputation error by the site.

Comment: It's starting to become quite likely that this is a congestion problem on the WiFi channel. I think you have enough information now to contact your university IT department and ask them to look into it. Make sure to mention the high number of WiFi signals, what channel they are on, and what channel has the least WiFi signals (so they can switch to this)

Comment: These all are in same channel 1 2412Mhz. These all the networks of university . All for different departments. One for faculty, one boys , non hostler etc.

Comment: Could you go out into the hallway and try and see what brand/model the WiFi router is? :)

Comment: No because it is at height and there is indication over it.

Comment: Time to just contact your IT department then...

Answer (score 0):

Answer by bill012, stolen from [here](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/wifi-signal-strength-excellent-slow-speed-555914/).

"There is difference between signal strength and signal quality. You can have a very strong signal but be getting huge number of errors because of interference. There are some wireless cards that display both strength and quality or error rates.

No easy way to fix this. Standard change the channel and see if its better. Many things can cause interference. You would have to think if you had any new devices in your house lately that use wireless. You could also turn off all but one of your devices and test. You may have some new software sending junk out. Of course it could just be a new router at a neighbors house on the same channel."

This falls in line with what @mtak suggests, and it explains why the signal strength looks ok. Since the speed is fine when you are nearby the router, the problem must be signal quality. So not it is just a matter of figuring out what is causing the interference. Other WiFi signals? Electric devices? ...

You could look/ask around for a tool that measures WiFi signal *quality* instead of signal *strength*. And then walk around your hall/room to detect the source of the interference... Yet, I'm no expert in this...